# Is it possible to copy a list item to a document library in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow, listitem, sharepointdocumentlibrary

How could I copy a list item, when it is created, to a document library using a workflow? Is it even possible?

If not, what would be a possible solution for getting a created list item to a document library?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have thought so. Instead of copying the item, could you consider adding the "Link to a Document" content type to the Doc Lib and get your Workflow to create a link back to the item?

Comment: Good idea, let me give it a try.

Comment: How do I create a link in the document library from the list using a workflow?

Comment: In a nutshell. Get a reference to the doc lib; Add an item to the doc lib; Change the content type of the item to be that of "Link to a Document"; Update the item; Set the link url to that of the item. Update the item to set the value. Does that help?

Comment: Does this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489477/sharepoint-change-content-type-in-sharepoint-designer-using-workflow

Comment: OK, i have it where is creates a "Link to a Document" in the document library, but it doesn't set the URL to the list item correctly. Everything is right until the end where is puts ".../1_.000".